# How do I transfer files using FileZilla via command line?

Tags: command-line, filezilla

How can I transfer files to a particular server using the command line using [FileZilla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FileZilla)?

Is it possible firstly?

Comment: Related: [FileZilla client run in command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073211/filezilla-client-run-in-command-line).

Answer (score 5):

> **Command line using FileZilla[?]**

FileZilla isn't a command-line program; it is a GUI program.

As far as I know, almost all versions of Windows have a command-line `ftp` command.

If you need something better, I suggest [a Windows port](ftp://ftp.ncftp.com/ncftp/binaries/Setup%20NcFTP%203.2.5.msi) of [`ncftpput`](http://www.ncftp.com/ncftp/doc/ncftpput.html):

> The purpose of ncftpput is to do file transfers from the command-line
>   without entering an interactive shell. This lets you write shell
>   scripts or other unattended processes that can do FTP. It is also
>   useful for advanced users who want to send files from the shell
>   command line without entering an interactive FTP program such as
>   ncftp.

…

> You can upload an entire directory tree of files by using the -R flag.
>   Example:
>
> ```
> $ ncftpput -R pikachu.nintendo.co.jp /incoming /tmp/stuff
> ```
>
> This would create a /incoming/stuff hierarchy on the remote host.

Comment: So should I install the Windows Port you suggested and then may be transfer files using comand line .thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

FileZilla does provide a separate CLI program. (in their PRO version)
https://filezillapro.com/docs/v3/filezilla-pro-cli/filezilla-command-line/